# Upgrading ActiveMQ from 5.4.2 to 5.11.1

Tags: java, jboss, activemq-classic

Desc of the environment:

- JBoss AS 5.1 GA
- ActiveMQ 5.4.2 embedded in JBoss.

Now, I have two questions.

First one is regarding upgrading ActiveMQ.
Is there any complex procedure that needs to be accomplished, or is it enough just to replace activemq-ra.rar folder with a newer version (5.11.1)?

And the second question: 
Is JBoss 5.1 GA compatible with the newest version of ActiveMQ(5.11.1)?

I have configured it to run in JBoss but the following exception is trown:

```
20150708T164913,707Z WARN  [ClassLoaderManager] Unexpected error during load of:org.apache.activemq.broker.jmx.MBeanInfo
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/activemq/broker/jmx/MBeanInfo : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem compatible. Active mq 5.11 uses jdk7 but jboss 5.1 is with jdk6.  See the release notes for reference 
http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-5110-release.html

Comment: Thanks, you are right.
Is there any documentation on upgrading ActiveMQ ?